Is it possible to read an executable and run it without writing it into another file?
I want something like where i have an executable and I can read that executable and I am able to read and store it into some variable and than with some interaction with that variable I can run the executable.
fn main() -> io::Result<()> {

        const BUFFER_SIZE: usize = 4096; 
    
        let input_path = "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/exp/target/debug/exp";
    
        let mut file = File::open(input_path)?;
        let mut contents = Vec::new();
        file.read_to_end(&mut contents)?;
    
        let bytes_to_copy = contents.len().min(BUFFER_SIZE);
    
        unsafe {
            let mem_address = libc::mmap(
                ptr::null_mut(),
                bytes_to_copy,
                libc::PROT_READ | libc::PROT_WRITE | libc::PROT_EXEC,
                libc::MAP_PRIVATE | libc::MAP_ANONYMOUS,
                -1,
                0,
            );
    
            if mem_address == libc::MAP_FAILED {
                panic!("mmap failed: {}", io::Error::last_os_error());
            }
    
            ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(contents.as_ptr(), mem_address as *mut u8, bytes_to_copy);
    
            // Ensure memory is executable
            let result = libc::mprotect(
                mem_address,
                bytes_to_copy,
                libc::PROT_READ | libc::PROT_EXEC,
            );
    
            if result != 0 {
                panic!("mprotect failed: {}", io::Error::last_os_error());
            }
    
            // Cast the memory address to a function pointer and call it
            let code: extern "C" fn() = std::mem::transmute(mem_address as *const ());
            code();
        }
    
        Ok(())
    }

So I tried this but it gives me seg fault. What am I doing wrong?

You can't just call an executable, it's not a function, it's a binary with structure.

There are different sections: code, data, BSS. The loader extracts these into different segments of memory. And if it's dynamically linked, it calls ld.so to do the runtime linking.

Generally speaking, there is a lot more to running a program than loading a binary image into memory and jumping to some entry point.  If you have to ask the question here, then you probably are not presently equipped to make anything like this work.

All you have to do is read the executable, interpret its format, set up program sections as it directs, do the same for dynamic libraries it refers to, fix up relocation references, set up the process environment, and jump to the entry point. Just everything the system program loader does, that’s all.

It's not at all clear why you're trying to do this.  Is it just out of academic interest, or are you actually trying to do this because you think it's a solution to some problem you're facing?  If the latter, this is almost certainly an XY Problem.

What I am trying to do is to read one executable and than write it into /proc/self/mem. I am able to perfectly write into it. But I am not sure, how do I call it to get the binary executed. The most I have been able to achieve is to get it printed.

You have to do a LOT more than execute it, that's the problem. Dynamically loading a file like this is usually done as a dll/shared object which is its own format and you wouldn't implement it yourself.

@MuhammadHassnain Are you trying to replace your program with another? If so, then you probably want to use execvp instead.

if you only don't want to write to a file, then take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63762804/17188368

The memfd_create + fexecve combo might just work for you (assuming a unix-like system): using memfd_create and fexecve to run ELF from memory

You can't run general executable in a such way. At least it should be compiled as flat position-independent binary for this.
